# Bulk deleting entries from a model efficiently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Let's say I have a model Books. I want to remove all entries which are created before a certain date and books that meet a certain condition, books without an ISBN.

Would fetching ids and running a delete job in batches be the most efficient way?
Note:- I am aware that delete is faster than destroy_all but I don't wish to skip callbacks in this case.

Example

```
Books.select(:id).where(isbn: nil).find_in_batches(batch_size: 1000) do |ids|
  Books.where(id: ids).destroy_all
end
```

Comment: The find_in_batches method yields a "batch" not a list of ids. So the second query should be `Book.where(id: batch.map(&:id)).destroy_all`. Note Book s/b singular in both cases. You should write a test to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`destroy_all` is the same as:

```rb
books.each(&:destroy)
```

As you can see in [source code](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActiveRecord/Relation/destroy_all)

So you can just:

```rb
Books.select(:id).where(isbn: nil).find_in_batches(batch_size: 1000) do |books|
  # since destroy_all is only a ActiveRecord::Relation method
  books.each(&:destroy)
end
```

This is the minimal query setup to do this the most efficiently way and yet getting your callbacks fired.

Note: if your callbacks need any other attribute than `id` loaded, you should add it to your `select` query.

Comment: This would create a DELETE query for each object no? Wouldn't that lead to a lot of I/O ops?

Comment: Yes, this would and it's not desirable. But that's the way you can assure callbacks are going to be called. Unfortunatelly, Rails itself has no efficient way to handle massive update/delete and yet use callbacks. You can try to improve it using Arel or you can try to load all those records into memory, use `delete_all` and then `run_callbacks` on them. But there are a couple of disadvantages of doing so: `run_callbacks` won't work with `after_update_commit`, or any callback using `on:`. Also, you will lose tracking of changes from ActiveModel::Dirty (you may wanna use those on callbacks)

Comment: Thank you SO much this was really informational!